# Perl, убить процесс по имени

Tags: perl, unix

Каждый запуск скрипта из консоли порождает 6 процессов: один родительский
процесс и 5 дочерних, которые порождаются родительским процессом. Без них
в браузере при попытке открыть скрипт будет ошибка. Заданием лабораторной
работы является сделать так, чтобы при каждом новом запуске скрипта из
консоли, старые процессы убивались, иначе будет ошибка о том, что порт на
котором вы пытаетесь запустить новый процесс уже занят.

Написано что можно использовать линукс команды, нашел kill для номера pid и killall для имени. 
killall perl-fcgi-pm убивает менеджера и дочерние процессы, все как нужно.
Как их прописать в скрипте и в каком месте?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
use DBI;
use FCGI::ProcManager qw(pm_manage pm_pre_dispatch pm_post_dispatch
pm_change_process_name);
use FCGI;
use POSIX qw(setuid setsid);
use Encode qw(decode encode _utf8_on);
my $dbh=DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=test_db1;host=localhost","test","test",
{AutoCommit=>1})
or print "mysql connect fail\n";
$dbh->{mysql_auto_reconnect} = 1;
fork_proc() && exit 0;
setsid() or die "Can't set sid: $!";
#33 - uid www-data
setuid(33) or die "Can't set uid: $!";
# Запущенный скрипт будет слушать 8090 порт
my $socket = FCGI::OpenSocket("127.0.0.1:8090", 1000);
my $request = FCGI::Request(\*STDIN, \*STDOUT, \*STDERR, \%ENV, $socket);
# будет 5 дочерних процессов
pm_manage(n_processes => 5);
pm_change_process_name("perl-fcgi-lab2");
# бесконечный цикл, который будет обрабатывать запросы
while($request->Accept() >= 0) {
pm_pre_dispatch();
my $query = CGI->new();
my $t = $query->param("t");
print "Content-Type: text/html\n";
print "\n";
if ($t eq "save") {
my $fio = $query->param("fio");
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES(null,?);");
$sth->execute($fio);
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM test_tab;");
$sth->execute();
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
print $row[1]."<br>";
}
print $fio."<br>";
}
print "<html><head></head><body>".
"<form action='/index.pl'>".
"<input type='hidden' name='t' value='save'>".
"<input type='text' name='fio'>".
"<input type='submit'>".
"</form>".
"</body></html>";
undef @CGI::QUERY_PARAM;
pm_post_dispatch();
};
$dbh->disconnect();
sub fork_proc {
my $pid;
FORK: {
if (defined($pid = fork)) {
return $pid;
}
elsif ($! =~ /No more process/) {
sleep 5;
redo FORK;
}
else {
die "Can't fork: $!";
};
};
};
sub reopen_std {
open(STDIN, "+>/dev/null") or die "Can't open STDIN: $!";
open(STDOUT, "+>&STDIN") or die "Can't open STDOUT: $!";
open(STDERR, "+>&STDIN") or die "Can't open STDERR: $!";
};
```

Answer (score 2):

наиболее логичное место для применения этих команд — в самом начале вашего скрипта, до каких-либо активных действий (как минимум, до попытки создания новых дочерних процессов). в вашем случае — можно сразу после строки с [шебангом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_%28Unix%29).

выполнить внешнюю (по отношению к интерпретатору) программу можно [разными способами](http://perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands). для вашего случая вполне подойдёт вызов функции `system()`:

```
system("killall имя");
```

Answer (score 0):

Сохраняйте PID родительского процесса, который хранится в "магической переменной" *$$*, в файл-семафор, на пример, */tmp/myprog.pid*. При каждом запуске проверяйте наличие такого файла и убивайте процесс по PIDу посредством *kill*.